# ERROR : "Expected a value of type 'List<int>', but got one of type 'Null'"

Tags: excel, flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter2.0

Recently i'm getting this Error in flutter trying to test if Excel file been created or not.the thing is that i used the same code in one of the oldest project and worked perfectly. I'm trying to use the web Device so when i press the Button the Excel file will be created and the download will start.

here my code :

```
import 'package:excel/excel.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  
  

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        
      body: ListView(
        children: [
           ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text(
                    "Save File",
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                   
                    final excell = Excel.createExcel();
                    final sheet = excell['Assets'];
                    var fileBytes = excell.save(fileName: "My_File_Name.xlsx");
                    
                  },
                ),
        ],
      )
      );
  }
}
```

this is the Error When i press the button :

> ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE
> ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown while handling a gesture:
> Expected a value of type 'List', but got one of type 'Null'
>
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/*internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart
> 251:49      throw*
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart
> 84:3        castError
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart
> 452:10  cast
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/classes.dart
> 635:14     as_C         packages/archive/src/zip_encoder.dart 90:34
> getFileCrc32packages/archive/src/zip_encoder.dart 135:15
> addFile      packages/archive/src/zip_encoder.dart 65:7
> encode       packages/excel/src/save/save_file.dart 36:25
> [_save]      packages/excel/src/excel.dart 334:20
> save packages/finance_refa/main.dart 46:43
>  packages/flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart 1005:21
> [_handleTap]packages/flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart 198:24
> invokeCallback packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 613:48
> handleTapUp packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 298:5
> [_checkUp]   packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 232:7
> handlePrimaryPointer packages/flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart
> 563:9
> handleEvent  packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 94:12
> [_dispatch] packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 139:9
>
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/linked_hash_map.dart
> 21:13          forEach
> packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 137:17
> [_dispatchEventToRoutes]
> packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 123:7
> route        packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 445:19
> handleEvent  packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 425:14
> dispatchEvent packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 326:11
> dispatchEvent packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 380:7
> [_handlePointerEventImmediately]
> packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 344:5 handlePointerEvent
> packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 302:7
> [_flushPointerEventQueue] packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart
> 285:32 [_handlePointerDataPacket]
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart
> 1075:13               invoke1
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart
> 185:5 invokeOnPointerDataPacket
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart
> 130:39 [_onPointerData]
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart
> 543:18                    
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart
> 496:21                    
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart
> 210:16 loggedHandler
>
> Handler: "onTap" Recognizer:   TapGestureRecognizer#f5722
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Comment: Stacktrace I guess points to `excell.save(...)` as the line in your code where the error happens. I don't know if you're using a third-party package to create the Excel file or else, but the problem is inside that method. Either look for support if it's a package, or debug your code to see where a variable supposed to be a `List` has become `null`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the third-party package [Excel](https://github.com/justkawal/excel). The issue you are describing has been fixed in the latest null-safety branch.

To use the latest null-safety branch in your project, use this in your pubspec.yaml:

```
  excel:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/justkawal/excel.git
      ref: null-safety
```

Please pay attention that this might probably not be a stable branch / version but will temporary fix your issue.